# Getting the COUNT and SUM of rows grouped by category in a prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, count, group-by, prepared-statement

I have the following prepared statement which returns the rows found for a particular category:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Work,Amount from work_times where Category=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $category);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($work,$amount);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $work.": &pound;".$amount." each<br>";
    }
```

What I would like to do is to adapt this to group the rows by the 'Work' column and then the 'Amount' column, returning one row for each group with a SUM and Count for each row/group, so that I can output something like this:

**5** consultancy sessions @ £**50** each: **£250**

1st February 2013
8th February 2013
15th February 2013
22nd February 2013
1st March 2013

**3** therapy sessions @ £**40** each: **£120**

2nd February 2013
9th February 2013
16th February 2013

**2** therapy sessions @ £**20** each: **£40**

3rd February 2013
10th February 2013

Where the text in bold in each row corresponds to: Count of rows in group, Amount (for each session), and Sum of the Amount values for each row in the group.  I hope this is clear!

I am not sure how to adapt the statement above to achieve this though.

**The above would be the result from the following table:**

```
ID | Work                | Amount

1  | Therapy Session     | £40     | 2013-02-02
2  | Consultancy Session | £50     | 2013-02-01
3  | Therapy Session     | £20     | 2013-02-03
4  | Consultancy Session | £50     | 2013-02-08
5  | Consultancy Session | £50     | 2013-02-15
6  | Therapy Session     | £40     | 2013-02-09
7  | Consultancy Session | £50     | 2013-02-22
8  | Therapy Session     | £40     | 2013-02-16
9  | Therapy Session     | £20     | 2013-02-10
10 | Consultancy Session | £50     | 2013-03-01
```

Ordering the groups by the count of rows, as in the above output would ideally be what I am looking for.

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result?

Comment: `ORDER by Date` without selecting `Date`?

Comment: @JW I have now added sample records

Comment: @njk I have removed ORDER by Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT `Work`, COUNT(*) AS sessions, SUM(`Amount`) AS Total
FROM work_times
GROUP BY `Work`, `Amount`
```

**Result**

```
|                WORK | SESSIONS | TOTAL |
------------------------------------------
| Consultancy Session |        5 |   250 |
|     Therapy Session |        2 |    40 |
|     Therapy Session |        3 |   120 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29b2c/1)

Comment: Oh, just one more thing.  Is there a way of returning each of the rows for a group? - I would like to echo the dates of each of the sessions in each group below each group.  So there would be 5 dates below the first group, 2 below the second and 3 below the third.    Because I am grouping the sessions in the query I am not sure how to refer to individual rows.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want, but sounds like you can use a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: I have changed the question above to include the output I am looking for, i.e. the dates for each session below each group.

Comment: I would suggest that you create a new question as this one has lost its original meaning. To accomplish what you want, you will need an inner loop to find the times of each "session"

Comment: OK, I will ask a new question about getting the dates for each session.  Any idea why `Sum(Amount)` isn't returning the SUM for each grouping, i.e. £250 for the first grouping, but rather is returning £50?  This seems to still be on topic for the original question!

Comment: I have the `SUM(Amount)` working now. I got confused between the SUM for each group and the SUM for all groups.  Thanks for your help.